# How to get a varchar which contains a (') in server-side processing datatable?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatable

I am trying to add QUOTE() function to this query. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_quote like this. How do i do it? This is a query which loads data from the database for column object

```
 "SELECT `".implode("`, `", self::pluck($columns, 'db'))."`
                 FROM `$table`
                 $where
                 $order
                 $limit"
```

I am trying to get data in my database to a datatable.  The code works if the column selected from database does not have a ('). I have a column in my database which contains varchar value and in that column there are user entries such as " what a lovel'y day!A@??ASD " as such. If this is the case the datatable won't load. How do i make this work?

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>



    <?php
 
/*
 * DataTables example server-side processing script.
 *
 * Please note that this script is intentionally extremely simple to show how
 * server-side processing can be implemented, and probably shouldn't be used as
 * the basis for a large complex system. It is suitable for simple use cases as
 * for learning.
 *
 * See http://datatables.net/usage/server-side for full details on the server-
 * side processing requirements of DataTables.
 *
 * @license MIT - http://datatables.net/license_mit
 */
 
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * Easy set variables
 */
 
// DB table to use
$table = 'datatables_demo';
 
// Table's primary key
$primaryKey = 'id';
 
// Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables.
// The `db` parameter represents the column name in the database, while the `dt`
// parameter represents the DataTables column identifier. In this case simple
// indexes
$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'first_name', 'dt' => 0 ),
    array( 'db' => 'last_name',  'dt' => 1 ),
    array( 'db' => 'position',   'dt' => 2 ),
    array( 'db' => 'office',     'dt' => 3 ),
    array(
        'db'        => 'start_date',
        'dt'        => 4,
        'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
            return date( 'jS M y', strtotime($d));
        }
    ),
    array(
        'db'        => 'salary',
        'dt'        => 5,
        'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
            return '$'.number_format($d);
        }
    )
);
 
// SQL server connection information
$sql_details = array(
    'user' => '',
    'pass' => '',
    'db'   => '',
    'host' => ''
);
 
 
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * If you just want to use the basic configuration for DataTables with PHP
 * server-side, there is no need to edit below this line.
 */
 
require( 'ssp.class.php' );
 
echo json_encode(
    SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
);




static function simple ( $request, $conn, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
    {
        $bindings = array();
        $db = self::db( $conn );

        // Build the SQL query string from the request
        $limit = self::limit( $request, $columns );
        $order = self::order( $request, $columns );
        $where = self::filter( $request, $columns, $bindings );

        // Main query to actually get the data
        $data = self::sql_exec( $db, $bindings,
            "SELECT `".implode("`, `", self::pluck($columns, 'db'))."`
             FROM `$table`
             $where
             $order
             $limit"
        );

        // Data set length after filtering
        $resFilterLength = self::sql_exec( $db, $bindings,
            "SELECT COUNT(`{$primaryKey}`)
             FROM   `$table`
             $where"
        );
        $recordsFiltered = $resFilterLength[0][0];

        // Total data set length
        $resTotalLength = self::sql_exec( $db,
            "SELECT COUNT(`{$primaryKey}`)
             FROM   `$table`"
        );
        $recordsTotal = $resTotalLength[0][0];

        /*
         * Output
         */
        return array(
            "draw"            => isset ( $request['draw'] ) ?
                intval( $request['draw'] ) :
                0,
            "recordsTotal"    => intval( $recordsTotal ),
            "recordsFiltered" => intval( $recordsFiltered ),
            "data"            => self::data_output( $columns, $data )
        );
    }
```

Comment: `array(
        'db'        => 'task',
        'dt'        => 3,
        'formatter' => function ($d, $row) {
            return str_replace("'", "", $d);
        }
    ),` I tried this but this does not work

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the single quote in the string with two single quotes.

```
$string = " what a lovel'y day!A@??ASD ";
$replace = str_replace("'", "''", $string);
```

This should work.

Comment: I have to fix this without altering the data. Data is already in the database. And i have to load it as it is.

Comment: @helloImstuck My bad. Misread what you were trying to do. You try using [QUOTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_quote) on your column?

Comment: "SELECT `".implode("`, `", self::pluck($columns, 'db'))."` FROM `$table` $where  $order $limit"  How do i add QUOTE to this query